# React Testing Library - React Select always displays Loading Message in the debug output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component that has an Async React Select in it, where the default loading message is `Loading...` and In my test file, I'm using `loadOptions` function to fetch the dropdown labels, in that function there is a setTimeout(() => {}, 1000) due to which for 1 sec my component displays loading message. No the problem I'm facing is whenever I try to test that component, it gives me the error message couldn't find an element (when I try to `screen.debug`, it prints the loading message in the `dom`) and If I try to put my expect statements into a setTimeout and waitFor, its getting skipped.

my screen.debug output -
[![my screen.debug output][1]][1]

My Test file -

```
it('...', () => {
   ....
const inputField = container.querySelector('input')
    
    act(() => {
      fireEvent.focus(inputField);
      fireEvent.keyDown(inputField, { key: 'ArrowDown', code: 40 });
    })
    screen.debug(container,Infinity)
   ...
}(
```

My Component -

```
const MyComp = () => {
const loadOptions = async () => {
   await setTimeout(() => {
   }, 1000) // just for the sake of displaying loader message, cannot be removed
   ...other data fetching logic
}
...
return
(
...
<Select
   loadOptions = {loadOptions}
   ...
   />
...
)}
```

How can I proceed further with this kind of scenario
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXXA7.png

Comment: You need to [mock the timers](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks) during your test to be able to control when the loading should disappear.